# Apache reverse proxy to Node server bypass

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, node.js

I have an Apache server that is working as a reverse proxy to a node server. I'm trying to bypass the proxy for a static file i.e. ads.txt

I have the following conf:

```
  <Files "ads.txt"> 
      Order Deny,Allow 
      Allow from all
  </Files>
  <Location "/ads.txt">
     SetHandler None
     Require all granted
  </Location>
  ProxyPass /ads.txt !  
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

But this causes a redirect loop when trying to access https://www.example.com/ads.txt and has me stumped. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks

Comment: At first glance the `Files` and `Location` blocks are completely redundant, but otherwise the syntax appears OK. What do your log files say?

Comment: Simply: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [06/Jan/2022:10:01:41 +0000] "GET /ads.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 244

Comment: Is there a .htaccess file or anything else in the Apache http configuration files with redirect and/or mod_rewrite rules?

Comment: Not that I can find. So it's going to be something stupid on my part. :(

Comment: I corrected this be rebuilding the server.